# Python отбирать каждые 2 элемента списка и оставшийся

Tags: python, list

Например есть список: `list = [1,2,3,4,5]`

Нужно добиться такого:

```
Получили 1,2 применили в функции
Получили 3,4 применили в функции
Получили 5 применили в функции
```

Comment: Что значит `применили в функции`? Применили как строку? Применили как два параметра (что делать с последним кортежем из одного элемента)? Постарайтесь задавать более развернутые вопросы...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
len_list = len(list)

def func(i):
    it =[item for item in list[i:i+2]]
    return it

for j in range(len_list//2 + len_list%2):
    i = j*2
    result = func(i)
    # обрабатывайте
    print(result)


[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5]
```

Comment: Непонятно как работать со значениями [1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5] мне нужно их обрабатывать в процессе цикла

Comment: Пожалуйста,  обрабатывайте в процессе цикла

Comment: Не стоит называть переменную list. Есть встроенная функция list().

Comment: Не подскажите, возможно ли будет сделать в будущем чтобы отбирал каждые 20 элементов? Что для этого нужно будет поменять?

Comment: замените `2` на `20` везде где видите :)

Comment: я так и подумал! но если вывожу менее 20 элементов, то цикл начинает выводить мне пустые списки [][][][][][][]

Comment: `for j in range(len_list//20 + (0 if len_list%20==0 else 1))`